# Since water is a molecule, can the aerosol sprayed through double slit form interference pattern?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, water, double-slit-experiment, molecules

A water molecule is made of 1 oxygen atom and 2 hydrogen atoms, so it is very small, like quantum scale small. So if I accelerate a bunch of these water molecules through the double slit using a spray then would I see an interference pattern on the screen? Intuition tells me no but my gut feeling is saying otherwise...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, not with a spray.

The reason for this is that "sprays" are not *isolated molecules*. They are *fine droplets*, and the individual droplets are still *vastly* larger than a molecule - a molecule is on order of 0.2 nm in size, but a droplet is >1000 nm. Hence, the *droplets* will not display sensible quantum behaviors of the type you are looking for.

Now you might ask about vapor or steam, i.e. water gas, which truly is separated to a molecular level. The problem there is that the molecular motions are randomized, by which I don't mean the "quantum-random" sense but the "thermal-random" sense. In terms of the position wave functions for the centers of mass of the molecules, which is what you want to try to get to behave nontrivially, they will be essentially waves of random and incoherent shape and direction(*). To get the double-slit pattern, you need *coherent* waves - same shape, same direction, synchronized phases. This means you need a molecular *gun* that is capable of regulating speed, direction, and timing accordingly - just as to do it with electrons, you need an electron gun.

---

(*) Technically, we don't really want to even talk "wave functions" at all here, because there is going to (almost surely) be entanglement due to molecular collisions (which thermalize the gas), which is how we can treat the gas as a classical gas for the purposes of, say, the ideal gas law. The entanglement means an individual molecule's kinematics are "decohered" with regard to the rest and can be treated as though it has an unknown, but actually much more localized, positional wave function. In a sense, the quantum "fuzziness" has been sucked from the molecule and transferred onto the surrounding gas. This is called a "mixed state"; mathematically it is represented via a *density operator* and not a Hilbert vector (those "$|\psi\rangle$" things) or a wave function. The analogue of a wave function for density operators is the density matrix, which is a function of *two* parameters. A more "physical" version of this is the *Wigner function,* which gives a "never-localizable" distribution where the two parameters are position *and momentum* simultaneously. We can still take the marginal for either, of course, which will be a *probability density function* or pdf, but this is not the same as a "wave function", because the wave function includes phase information.

Comment: @Jirka Hanika: If the gas is thermalized, as we can usually approximate, it will almost surely have gotten that way by molecules colliding with each other.

Comment: Wouldn't the slits behave rather like a pair of nozzles?

Comment: @MikeB: Hmm. You're right, I'd think so. When I first answered this, I remembered some diffraction experiments had been done using "buckyballs" which are actually considerably _bigger_ than water molecules, but not the details. I just decided to look it up, and there's a schematic here: https://quantumnano.at/research/universal-matter-waves/far-field-diffraction/the-origin-c60-diffraction/ which kinda suggests the experiment is not too different from this! But note though you also need a velocity selector - I forgot to mention that the wavelength also matters.

Comment: (Pretty crucially, actually. By sending different wavelengths you are in effect sampling a mixture of diffraction patterns of different scales, and thus the final distribution at the screen will still look "classical" as the troughs and peaks get mashed up with those of other distributions.)

Comment: This doesn't contravene what I said earlier in the answer, though: note that while a slit _does_ indeed "serve as a nozzle" in this setup, it's _not_ the diffracting slit; you want to put a slit _before_ the diffracting one as a _source_ i.e. a collimator. "Nozzling" of the molecules _after_ doesn't help because the whole point is that the _waves_ need to have spread out _before_ they hit the _slits._ You can see this in the diagram; in fact there are two nozzling stages, not one.

Comment: Given that interference patterns can be created with much larger molecules than H2O such as bucky-balls, I'm not sure how you can assert that an electron gun is required.

Comment: @JimmyJames: I did not say a gun was the _only_ means, only that naively spraying aerosol through the slits with a spray can is _not_ a means, and why.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer OK, I see now.  The wording in the last sentence of the first section "... you need an electron gun" threw me off.  I saw some old MIT video on youtube the other day where created an apparatus to vaporize cesium (I think, it was late) and send it through a detector as a stream of molecules.  They used a couple of razor blades to control the width of the stream.  Perhaps something along those lines could work for this.

Comment: @JimmyJames : Yes. Note my link which describes the Buckyball experiment explicitly. You will need more than a slit though, you will also need some way to ensure the velocities and so wavelengths are about equal. Remember you're picking molecules out of a Maxwellian (or approximately so, at least) distribution. So you need to ensure only molecules of similar velocities make it to the screen, while turning away those of substantially different velocity. That's also why I mentioned a gun: a gun lets you control the velocity directly, which is more efficient.

Answer (score 11):

The deBroglie wavelength of a droplet of water can be calculated like any other particle:

$$\lambda = \frac{h}{mv}$$

Where $h = 6.62607015×10^{-34} \frac{J}{Hz}$ - at $100 \frac{m}{s}$ a 1000 nm radius sphere of water has a mass of $2.4 * 10^{-15}$ grams.

This gives a wavelength of about 3 nm.

As the wavelength is much smaller than the droplet, it will be hard to generate an interference pattern.

Dropping the speed down to 0.1 m/s makes the wavelength longer than the particle size.

The next hard part is not having the droplet self destruct, and avoiding it from accidentally being measured by interacting with photons and thus the environment.  Objects that are not extremely cold emit a LOT of photons (thermal heat), which makes them difficult to keep isolated.

So, super cool the droplet, send it at extremely slow speeds in a vacuum, super cool the environment, and you could get a quantum interference pattern.

I don't think we have the engineering capabilities to do this.

Comment: I feel like it is worth pointing out here that the typical problem for more massive molecules is actually wavelengths that are too *small*. As you increase the mass of the particle, the wavelength actually decreases. This wavelength is only unmeasurably large because the velocity of the droplet is non-relativistic (reasonable, since otherwise it would evaporate or turn to plasma), not because of the droplet being too massive.

Answer (score 5):

They have performed interference experiments with big molecules, but not in forms of sprays, since then collisions and interactions between the particles would lead to their decoherence and loss of quantum effects. But if you shoot one molecule through the double-slit setup, yes, it would interfere (if the length scales are properly sized).

Comment: Here's a link to the paper about doing the interference of Buckyballs/Fullerene/C60: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251170703_Wave-particle_duality_of_C60_molecules

Comment: This paper explains the level of decoherence in the above C60 experiment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.2307.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Every "entity" with mass has an associated deBroglie wavelength λ = h/mv. But because m is (relatively) large for droplets, λ becomes very small. But if you squint, even relatively large masses we'd normally treat classically [expose "quantum-ness"](https://www.wired.com/story/even-huge-molecules-follow-the-quantum-worlds-bizarre-rules/).

The limit of the quantum model for ever larger masses is the familiar, seemingly continuous behavior of macroscopic objects. Quantum effects are still there, but they become vanishingly small, and hence irrelevant. This resembles other improvements of classical physics for scales beyond everyday experience, notably relativity where the limit for slow velocities consists, unsurprisingly, of the laws of classical mechanics.